# How do i get the expected type in an expression using roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to develop a codefix for CS0417 and am stuck at finding out how to infer the type that is required to fix the overload resolution error.

Looking at [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Semantics/OverloadResolution/MethodTypeInference.cs) it appears that the code required to potentially find out which type is required is internal currently. Does anyone know a built in way to figure out that "string" is expected in the following code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TypeName
    {
        TypeName()
        {
            var action = new Func<int, string>(TestMethod);
        }

        private int TestMethod(int arg)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

You can pull [this](https://github.com/taori/Amusoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers/tree/features/cs1503-codefix) branch and debug the test method `Cs0407FixGenerateFixedReturn` to get started quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is fairly simple if the type is a delegate, which suits my needs:

```
            var creationSyntax = argumentSyntax.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (creationSyntax == null)
                return false;

            var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(creationSyntax.Type).Symbol;
            if (symbolInfo is INamedTypeSymbol namedType)
            {
                symbol = namedType?.DelegateInvokeMethod?.ReturnType;
                return symbol != null;
            }
```